# Extend image below its containing div

Tags: css, html, dom

I have an image which is inside a div. It appears as expected, within the div. When `margin-top` is added, the background for this div extends downwards. I don't want to have this behavior. How can I change this?

My code is as follows :

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="half">
      <p>Text goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <img src="imghere.png" alt="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.half {
  display:inline-block;
  width:44%;
  margin:0 2%;
}
```

This ensures that the column with the `<p>` tag goes on the left side of the screen, and the column with the image goes on the right, and it resizes as you resize the window :).

How can I make this webpage go from

```
-----div-----------
Text    Image
-----/div-----------
```

to

```
-----div------------
Text
--/div--Image----
```

Image illustrating what I would like :

[image]

Comment: It seems like an odd question. Don't you want the two items side by side? It's not really clear what the issue is. What are you adding the margin-top to, and what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @ralph.m Thanks for the question. I want the image on the right hand side to extend slightly below the div that contains it. I have added an image to illustrate what I mean. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/bH8qA/

Comment: I am a beginner in this field but I had a similar issue like yours.Did you try using z -index with which you can manipulate with any DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

I originally skipped over the fact that you provided some HTML and CSS in the question, so in my original answer I just went off the image provided. Looking at the HTML and CSS you provided, the only thing you'd have to do to get the desired result is set a negative bottom margin in your CSS on the `img` tag. Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9Xk/3/)</kbd> using your original markup with the only significant addition to the CSS being the negative bottom margin set on the `img` tag.

The added benefit of doing it this way is that the image will stay in the desired spot (extended slightly below the `div` that contains it), even when adding more lines of text to the paragraph (`p`) changes the height of the containing element (`.page div`).

**CSS**

```
.page {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.half {
    display:inline-block;
    width:44%;
    margin:0 2%;
}
img {
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

**Original answer:**

You could just position the image below the text, float the image, and set a negative top margin on the image to make it cut back into the element containing the text. This way, the image will keep sitting in the right spot, even when adding more lines of text changes the height of the containing element.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9Xk/1/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<p>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>Text
    <br/>
    <img />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;
    margin: -70px 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the question completely, but I coded what you wanted in css with your HTML untouched. Hopefully that helps. Check out the JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bH8qA/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="half">
                <p>Text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="half">
               <img src="imghere.png" alt="img" />
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page{
    background-color:#cc0000;
    border-top:4px solid #000;
    border-bottom:4px solid #000;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
}
.half{
    display:inline-block;
    width:44%;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:right;
}
.half + .half{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:4%;
}
.half > img{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F5EB00;
    border:4px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css and use the overflow: hidden on the parent of that div.

Comment: I have added a margin-top of 250px to the content div, and set overflow : hidden;. The div background still extends down with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/urGnL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.page {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red; 
}
.half{
    width:44%;
    margin:0 2%;
}

.float {
    float: right;
}

.page, img {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

img {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: yellow;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="half float">
               <img src="imghere.png" alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div class="half">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```